# Scan all ports from JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, sockets

How do I scan all ports from `JTextArea` whether the port is open or closed?

Comment: How exactly is JTextArea related to this? I would just concentrate on getting it to work without all that Swing noise and then once you got it to work, just wrap it in some helper class/method which you then call from your Swing app.

Answer (score 1):

Well as BalusC quite rightly pointed out, you really should get the non-GUI side of it pinned first.

Adapting slightly from the code provided at [java-samples.com](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=237), you could use this approach to scan each port:

```
public class PortScanner {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int startPortRange = 0;
        int stopPortRange = 65535;

        for (int i = startPortRange; i <= stopPortRange; i++) {
            try {
                Socket ServerSok = new Socket("127.0.0.1", i);

                System.out.println("Port in use: " + i);

                ServerSok.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            System.out.println("Port not in use: " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

I would strongly, strongly advise that you find a more optimised way of doing this however, as this method is incredibly slow (and I must admit I haven't checked that it works reliably- that is for you to do).

Comment: thanks very much.. but I mean, how to do a port scan that already exist in jtextearea

example: there are 50 ports and 50 IP in the jtextarea

so how to do a port scan of the existing data in jtextarea

Comment: @user: That question would need to be reformulated as: "How do I split a `String` from a `JTextArea` into a `String[]` (or whatever) so that I can pass it to the port scanner method?". One step at a time.

Comment: Well, using the code above I guess you could see that you can create a new Socket at the IP address, and based on what happens after that you can determine if it is open or closed. This then just needs doing for each IP address/port combination you would like.

I would suggest you try understanding the above code, and then look at code elsewhere for obtaining the textual content of a JTextArea.

Best of luck!